# React Native project using Ironsource SDK: "Current Activity does not exist." on Android

Tags: android, react-native, ironsource

I use ironsource-mediation package for my react native project (Android only project). Some of my user's app is crashing and I can't figure out why. My app works fine on my test devices, tried 5+ devices and they are all fine. I added Sentry to my project and here's the info that I have:

React Native version: 0.73.1
My build gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")
    implementation("com.facebook.react:flipper-integration")
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:18.0.1' 
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.0.0' 
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appset:16.0.2' 

    implementation 'com.ironsource.sdk:mediationsdk:7.7.0' 
    // Add UnityAds Network
    implementation 'com.ironsource.adapters:unityadsadapter:4.3.34'
    implementation 'com.unity3d.ads:unity-ads:4.9.2'


    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}
```

project level build gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        ndkVersion = "25.1.8937393"
        kotlinVersion = "1.8.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin")
    }
}
```

package.json dependency for ironsource:

```
"ironsource-mediation": "^1.1.0",
```

[image]

You can see that the error is caused by irounsource-mediation library.